# brackets automatically loads preview

Tags: adobe-brackets

right when I open or whenever I click on the HTML file to activate my HTML file a preview shows up instead of the code that I'm working on. In the top left corner it says WYSIWYG Editor. My Brackets is Release 1.6 build 1.6.0-16680. I want to stop this preview, how do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the preview and press "prevent opening"